# Wentzel–Kramers–Brillouin Connection Formula Derivation

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, derivation-of-formulae

I'm reading 2nd edition of Merzbacher's *Quantum Mechanics*, and am having trouble following a step in his derivation of some formulas related to the Wentzel–Kramers–Brillouin approximation. On p. 118, the author gives as the WKB approximation to the wave function

\begin{equation*}
\psi(x) \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{k(x)}}\exp\left[\pm i\int_{}^{x}{k(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}\right]
\end{equation*}

where I think the lower bound being blank implies that it is a constant, and where

\begin{equation*}
k(x) = \left[\frac{2\mu}{\hbar^{2}}\left[E-V(x)\right]\right]^{1/2}
\end{equation*}

if $E>V(x)$, and $k(x) = -ik(x)$ if $E<V(x)$. In order to derive the "connection formulas" at the boundary, the author suggests making the substitutions

\begin{equation*}
v(x) = \sqrt{k(x)}\psi(x)\hspace{1pc}\mbox{ and }\hspace{1pc}y = \int_{}^{x}{k(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}.
\end{equation*}

Then he says "by a little manipulation, we obtain instead of the Schrödinger equation"

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}v}{\mathrm{d}y^{2}} + \left[\frac{1}{4k^{2}}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}k}{\mathrm{d}y}\right)^{2} - \frac{1}{2k}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}k}{\mathrm{d}y^{2}}+1\right]v = 0.
\end{equation*}

I'm not sure what manipulations he means, though. I've tried just taking the second derivative of $v$ with respect to $y$, which goes something like

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}v}{\mathrm{d}y^{2}} &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\left[\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}y}\right]\\
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\left[\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[\sqrt{k(x)}\psi(x)\right]\right)\right]\\
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\left[\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k(x)}}\frac{\mathrm{d}k}{\mathrm{d}x}\psi(x) + \sqrt{k(x)}\frac{\mathrm{d}\psi}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)\right]\\
&=\cdots
\end{align*}

Does this seem like the right way to derive the differential equation? Incidentally, since $k(x)>0$, is it safe to write

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} = \frac{1}{k(x)}?
\end{equation*}

Is the right way to go then to plug in the WKB approximation to $\psi$ and the explicit definition of $k(x)$?

Comment: Answer clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

You may be overthinking it, standing on your head. Note that, in natural units, *y* is dimensionless, and *v* has units of $k^{3/2}$, while $\partial_x= k\partial_y$. You then have the Schroedinger equation
$$
\partial_x^2 \frac{v}{\sqrt k} + k^{3/2} v=0 \leadsto \\
k\partial_y \left (k\partial_y  \frac{v}{\sqrt k}\right ) + k^{3/2} v=0 \leadsto \\
\partial_y\left (\sqrt{k} \partial_y v -\frac{\partial_yk~v}{2\sqrt{k}}\right )+ \sqrt{k} v=0 \leadsto \\
\partial_y^2 v+\frac{1}{k^2} (\partial_yk)^2 v -\frac{1}{2k}\partial_y^2k~~v +v=0,
$$
all dimensionally consistent.